# What is some poetry or famous lines/sayings on the "indifference to wealth and fame"?

Tags: word-choice, phrases, sentence, phrase-usage, poetry

I want to describe someone who is austere, stoic, having the purest soul, although living in this world full of the desires of wealth and status. Is the phrase "indifferent to wealth and fame" the correct usage? I would be very grateful if you could let me know any poetry or sayings related to this.

Comment: "Indifferent to wealth and fame" summarizes the person's views quite well, I think. With regard to sayings related to such views, I like these lines from the Old Testament book of Ecclesiastes (V, 10 and VI, 7): "He that loveth silver shall not be satisfied with silver; nor he that loveth abundance, with increase. This is also vanity." and "All the labour of man is for his mouth, and yet the appetite is not filled."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"The lust of fame is the last that a wise man shakes off." ~Tacitus

Famous German Philosopher Arthur Schopenhauer also agrees with the above quote, citing it in his book The Wisdom of Life.

This quotes highlights the attractiveness of fame and power, as well as the immense mental will to resist such desires.

Comment: But how does it refer to the 'indifference' of the person in question?

Answer (score 2):

> **Remain in the world, act in the world, do whatsoever is needful, and yet remain transcendental, aloof, detached, a lotus flower in the pond.**
>   ― Osho, The Secret of Secrets

This  is  what  is  called  detachment  the  philosophy  of  the GITA, the  sacred  Grandha( book) of  the Hindus.